# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, superfish

I am getting this error only in chrome for superfish drop down menu. It works fine in Firefox, and IE. It does not work in Chrome. The menu instead of being horizontal list itself Vertical. **domain name of clients actual site has been changed below for confidentiality**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domainname.com/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domainname.com/js/superfish.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domainname.com/js/hoverIntent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // initialise plugins
jQuery(function(){
     jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish();
    });
</script>
```

I have even changed it to the following and does not work:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $('ul.sf-menu').superfish();
         })
    </script>
```

I looked at the view source and it is referencing two header files. This could be causing the error. I am using magento. The menu is working on all pages of the site except the one page checkout.

**Fixed! read below will post as answer when it lets me in 7 hrs**

The issue was not with the javascript itself, but with the css for the superfish menu.
The developer who designed the layout and coded the template listed the stylesheet for the superfish menu as:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.domainname.com/css/superfish.css" media="screen">
```

After removing the "http://www.domainname.com" and leaving it as "/css/superfish.css" it fixed the menu.

Comment: I changed the actual domain of the website in the code above for client confidentiality.

Comment: Did you check your error console?

Comment: The error console is where I am getting the error. I am only getting this in chromes error console.

Comment: what happens when you load the url for jquery in chrome?

Comment: Are you sourcing the scripts from a CDN? Content blockers of various nature might block them

Comment: all of the script are referencing files from the site itself.

Comment: ok, are you accessing the site via HTTPS? Don't know of the default setting in Chrome. But it might block insecure content (HTTP). Usually shows a notice in the location bar, though

Comment: yes it is using an ssl, and blocking insecure content. I believe this is what is causing that to happen as well.

Comment: *"I believe this is what is causing that to happen as well."* Neither can I, FWIW.

Comment: Well, go for protocol-relative URLs then. Include `"//path"` instead of `"http://path"`. So `"//www.domain.com/js/jquery.js"`

Comment: found issue answer in edit above.

Comment: @n_starnes: How in heaven's name would that cause a `ReferenceError` on the `jQuery` symbol?!

Comment: it is not the cause of the reference error but was the cause of my primary issue which was the superfish menu not working at all.

Comment: yes, I have notified everyone so this does not happen again. Easily preventable and will no more time shall be lost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only reasons trying to use the symbol `jQuery` like that would cause a `ReferenceError` would be:

1. If the script include for jQuery failed. Check your console for 404s and the like.
2. If one of the later scripts actually *deletes* the `jQuery` `window` property, e.g.:

   ```
   delete window.jQuery;
   ```

   Just setting `jQuery` to `undefined` (perhaps via `noConflict`) wouldn't cause a `ReferenceError`, you'd get `undefined is not a function` or similar. But if you actually delete the property, then you would. (Except on IE, which won't let you delete properties from the `window` object.)

Comment: @n_starnes: Just updated (I thought of a second option, at least on non-IE browsers), but those really are the only two scenarios that I can think of. If you're not seeing an error in whatever browser you're using, try Chrome or Firefox+Firebug. Something is definitely going wrong somewhere.

Comment: I agree with this. Is there a chance the listed source isn't actually in the same order (that is, calling the 'initialize plugins' code before referencing the source script)?

Comment: I looked at the view source and it is referencing two header files. This could be causing the error. I am using magento. The menu is working on all pages of the site except the one page checkout.